# getOutputStream / getInputStream via sctp protocol

Tags: java, sctp

How to Returns an output stream for SCTP socket? for example in TCP (`socket.getOutputStream`). but how in SCTP? I've tried to searching, but I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing SCTP protocal in one of the JDK 7 features.

Example Link : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-139946.html